# Are "restricted programming" problems on topic?

Tags: discussion, policy, challenges, clarification

I'm not sure if "restricted programming" is the right term for what I'm thinking about.  I'm referring to questions of the form: "Complete [some task] in [some specific language] without [some obvious keywords, operators, etc.]".  For instance, requesting interesting ways to implement a particular Java interface without using `for` or `while`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I recall, one of the deciding factors is whether the contest can be fairly and objectively judged by some concrete metric.

So just being "interesting ways" would fail that criteria miserably. How do you quantify "interesting"?

Comment: `How do you quantify "interesting"?` The answer with the most upvotes :)

Comment: In all seriousness though I understand, and that makes sense.